# Split divs with class from html to be used by script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, masonry, imagesloaded

I am trying to build my own 'infinite scroll' so I have more control than using a plugin.

I currently have the below:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
      if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
         loadNew();
      }
}); 

function loadNew(){  
    var next = $('a.next').attr('href');

    $.ajax({
        url: next,
        success: function(html){

            ** GET ALL '.grid-item' TO USE BELOW**

            var $newElems = $( **ALL .grid-item** ).css({ opacity: 0 });
            $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
                $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
                $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

This is so far triggering when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page, its then getting the 'next' URL from the pagination and returning the full HTML of the page in the success call.

As you can see in my code, I want to get all divs with the class '.grid-item' to be used by the code below.

I am really struggling to get the '.grid-item' divs seperated to be used.

Is anyone able to explain how I can do this?

Comment: I think you should post the success HTML too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is convert the returned html to a jQuery object so that you can parse it using `find()` to get the relevant elements.  This is done easily by wrapping the html like this, `$(html)`, but if there is a doctype declaration then that will break it.  What I normally do is make sure I've only got data that starts from the opening html tag.

Try this...

```
function loadNew(){  
    var next = $('a.next').attr('href');

    $.ajax({
        url: next,
        success: function(html){
            html = html.substr("<html");    // remove the doctype
            var $newElems = $(html).find(".grid-item").css({ opacity: 0 });
            $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
                $container.append($newElems).masonry("appended", $newElems, true);
                $newElems.css({ opacity: 1 });
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Also, you need to first append the elements to the container, and *then* tell masonry that you've done so.  The masonry `appended` call doesn't actually append anything.

Comment: Thanks Archer. I am getting an object returned with:
Object[div.grid-inline.col-6.bp1-col-4.bp2-col-3.bp3-col-2.grid-item, div.grid-inline.col-6.bp1-col-4.bp2-col-3.bp3-col-2.grid-item, div.grid-inline.col-6.bp1-col-4.bp2-col-3.bp3-col-2.grid-item, div.grid-inline.col-6.bp1-col-4.bp2-col-3.bp3-col-2.grid-item, div.grid-inline.col-6.bp1-col-4.bp2-col-3.bp3-col-2.grid-item ... ]
I don't understand how I get this into a readable format to append to my html.

Comment: Does masonry require html when you append then?  If so it's a simple change to make it work.

Comment: The error 'TypeError: $newElems.outerHTML is not a function' is now thrown.

Comment: Okay - `.outerHTML()` gets the html from a jQuery object (or array of objects) so that will allow you to append it to your masonry container, but you'll probably need to set the opacity *after* you do this.  I've made the relevant change to the code to do this.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87254/discussion-between-ccdavies-and-archer).